# When I click the button, there is no sound effect

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask again, based on the answer I got to a question I had asked before. I'm trying to make a sound effect when the buttons are clicked in my project. I saw that the sound effect that I gave direction to the buttons did not materialize. Then I concluded as I posted below. But this doesn't work quite right.

```
<button href="index.html" type="button" class="menu-icon" onClick="playMyAudio()" preload="auto">Play Audio</button>
<audio src="sound/Message Pop.mp3" preload="auto" id="myAudio"></audio>

<script>
  const audioEl = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  function playMyAudio() {
    audioEl.play();
  }

  const buttonLinks = document.querySelectorAll("button[href]");
  const delay = 75;//milliseconds

  audioEl.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
    buttonLinks.forEach(btn => {
      btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.location = btn.getAttribute("href")
        }, audioEl.duration + delay);
      })
    });
  });
</script>
```

What method can I follow for a more effective result here?

In the final version, the buttons sometimes sound and sometimes do not.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your `href` is correct? Does the button disappear after a while clicking it? And is it replaced by a text like `not found`? If so `href` might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that I threw together of clicking a button to play an MP3 in Javascript.  I hope that this helps!

app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sound Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="soundButton">Click Me!</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
const soundButton = document.querySelector('#soundButton');

soundButton.addEventListener('click', function () { playSound(); });

function playSound() {
    const sound = new Audio('catMeowing.mp3').play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I add the href code to these buttons, it runs first. I want both sound and page change.